# Do you know a company called BLOCKCHAIN with email address "bitcoinrefunds.finance"?

Tags: wallet-recovery

In February 2022, I was contacted by a company BLOCKCHAIN (email address terminating by bitcoinrefunds.finance). They informed me that they can help me to recover previous investement in cryptos.
They told me that the money is blocked in a trust account by JAXXLIBERTY and that to release it I must obtain authorization by sending an important amount of money.
JAXXLIBERTY support (teamsupport@jaxxliberty.io) confirmed me that they will release my money as soon as they receive the money for authorization.
Is that a normal procedure?
Can I believe in BLOCKCHAIN?

Comment: No the company Blockchain should be contacting you using a blockchain.com email address. This looks like a scam to me.

Comment: It's almost certainly a scam, like many, *many* others surrounding recovering cryptocurrency funds. We get a *lot* of spam about such things here on SE, particularly on this SE site. In fact, your question has enough keywords which are similar to such spam such that it may be seen as such upon first glance (and, unfortunately, is, effectively, beneficial for them, given how search engines work).